# Display UIAlertView with UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput, but to not have it show keyboard

Tags: ios, ios6, uialertview, uikeyboard

So I have a situation where I wish to display a `UIAlertView` with the `alertViewStyle` as `UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput`, however I wish to have it so that when it shows up, it does not show the keyboard associated with it. Does anyone have an idea?

P.S. For how I want it to look, go ahead and display an alert view in the simulator with `alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput`, and then press return. I want the `UIAlertView` centered on the screen.

Comment: Why don't you want the keyboard up exactly?

Answer (score 1):

I just found a couple ways to do this. The first and dirtiest way would be to immediately call `resignFirstResponder`. It's ugly, but it works.

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"title" message:@"message" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" otherButtonTitles:@"Button", nil];
[alert setAlertViewStyle:UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput];
[alert show];
[[alert textFieldAtIndex:0] resignFirstResponder];
```

The second option would be to utilize the `UITextFieldDelegate` protocol, specifically `textFieldShouldBeginEditing:`. Using this and setting your class as the delegate of the text field in the alert, you can simply return `NO` and prevent the keyboard from being presented at all.

It is important to keep in mind that unless you provide some sort of condition within this method, you won't be able to edit the text field.

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"title" message:@"message" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" otherButtonTitles:@"Button", nil];
[alert setAlertViewStyle:UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput];
[[alert textFieldAtIndex:0] setDelegate:self];
[alert show];

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    return NO;
}
```

Comment: I had tried this and I noticed that doing this does not center the UIAlertView on the screen in the simulator. Is this true for you as well?

Answer (score 1):

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"title"
                                                message:@"")
                                               delegate:self
                                      cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                      otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];

alert.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;


UITextField *textField = [alert textFieldAtIndex:0];
textField.text = @"your text";
[alert show];
```

WORKS on IOS6 and IOS7

Answer (score 0):

This is just a theory and have not tested it:-

1. Create the UIAlertView
2. Execute something like the following :-

   ```
   for(UIView *view in [alertView subViews])
   {
    if([view isKindOfClass:[UITextField class])
   {
    view.delegate=self
   }
   }
   ```
3. implement the method

   ```
   - (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
   {
      return NO;
   }
   ```
4. show alertview

Answer (score 0):

```
for(UIView *view in alert.subviews)
    {
        if([view isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]])
        {
            UITextField *aux=(UITextField *)view;
            aux.text=@"text";
        }
    }
```

works in IOS6 but not works in IOS7